# I need someone to explain this ASP function to me

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

I've got an ASP document that 5 years old. Actually I'm working with PHP but I must use ASP for a Windows Application. So I need someone to explain this function to me.

//DNS SETTINGS ARE INCLUDED ALREADY.

```
function Check_Is_Web_Locked()
    dim cmdDB , Ret
    OpenDatabase 
    Set cmdDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
            With cmdDB
                .ActiveConnection = DBCon
                .CommandText = "TICT_CHECK_WEB_STATUS"
                .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 0)
                .Execute,,adExecuteNoRecords
                Ret = Trim(.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE"))

            End With
            Set cmdDB = Nothing
            CloseDatabase

            Check_Is_Web_Locked = Ret

end function
```

What does this function do?

Is "TICT_CHECK_WEB_STATUS" a stored procedure?

If it's what are the columns that function looking for?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that's classic ASP, not ASP.NET (re-tagged)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `TICT_CHECK_WEB_STATUS` is a stored procedure in the database. This SP returns a "signed integer" output parameter called `RETURN_VALUE`, whose value gets stored in the `Ret` variable when it is returned from the SP.

The `Trim` function should strip out any white-space from `RETURN_VALUE`, but since it is an integer there will never by any. Therefore it is simply converting the return value into a string.

Finally the function is returning the `Ret` string. This is done with the `Check_Is_Web_Locked = Ret` statement.

Comment: So.. What is ".Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@pTLoginName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15,strLoginName)" this line means?

Comment: @Ronnie: That would be passing an input parameter to the stored procedure. The stored procedure would be expecting the input parameter called `@pTLoginName` of type `varchar` (string). The `strLoginName` would be a variable in the ASP script. Basically you would be passing a value to the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you so so so much for these comments! I will try to fix my problem but is there any way to contact to you? I've got more questions :/

Comment: @Ronnie: Yes, feel free to send me an email at `mail@namesurname.com`. Replace `namesurname` with my real name and surname. However, I really suggest you post on Stack Overflow if you have more questions or require further assistance. You are almost guaranteed to get quality answers in here.

Comment: Thank you. I sent you a test e-mail. reply me if you got it :)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it's just a heartbeat of sorts to the database (i.e. the web page is saying "Hey Database, are you alive?" by calling `TICT_CHECK_WEB_STATUS`). And yes, `TICT_CHECK_WEB_STATUS` is a stored proc.

Answer (score 2):

TICT_CHECK_WEB_STATUS is apparently a stored proc that returns an output parameter value called Return_Value. That value is stored in a variable called Ret.